# SQL Server datetime field not showing exactly in C# as SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, string-formatting

I am creating a desktop application in which I have to query data in SQL Server by providing date and time. Interval is in seconds and every second I run the query again, with the next date.

In this scenario I am getting data from SQL Server and saving date column value on a label, after processing that data, I am running that query again with the date stored on that label and again..

But there's a problem that my SQL Server datetime column is showing as

```
2016-12-01 18:36:32.000
```

and when I access that column in my Winform label, it shows as

```
12/1/2016 6:36 PM
```

As I have mentioned that I have to consider seconds also, like in SQL Server my query is working fine because I can change minutes easily but when I try to load that same field on label, it is not showing as it is showing in SQL Server.

All I want is to get that column value the same as it is showing in SQL Server.

This is the code I am using to display datetime value on label.

I have selected the column from a simple SQL query like

```
SELECT [column name]
FROM [table name]

if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count>0)
{
    lblDate.Text = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CHECKTIME"].ToString();
    dgv.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
}
```

Screenshots of error

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRfSJ.jpg
- [http://imgur.com/a/sQtzu](https://imgur.com/a/sQtzu)

Comment: Is this really all the C# DateTime is storing? or is it *all you're displaying*?

Comment: i am just displaying data from database

Comment: i just want retrieved datetime same as it displays in sql server

Comment: But I suspect you're displaying it using the default formatting, which in your culture probably doesn't show seconds. This is a "how do I specify a custom format" question really, but we don't know how you're displaying the value at the moment, as you haven't shown any code.

Comment: ok will you please tell me how can i solve my problem?

Comment: Well what if you were to display `myDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");` - following your edit, you would specifically use `lblDate.Text = dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CHECKTIME"].ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");`

Comment: i have edited the question and added some code

Comment: DateTime is a *binary* value. It doesn't have *any* format. You confuse what your form or web pages shows for the actual value. If you change `ToString()` to use a long format you'll get the seconds too.

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre it says 'no overload for method toString takes 1 argument' when i tried your method

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos will you please tell me how i can chane ToString() to long? as it only displaying ToString() option there

Comment: @Axad `ToString` accepts a format parameter. Just look the documentation. There are some predefined formats, eg `ToString("s")` but you can also use custom formats. It's *very* easy to google for this

Comment: @Axad in that case try to cast to a `DateTime` first like so `lblDate.Text = (DateTime)(dataset.Tables[0].Rows[0]["CHECKTIME"]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff");`

Comment: @Axad check the [Formatting Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx) section of the docs. Formatting and parsing are a fundamental part of .NET. Understanding them can save you a lot of trouble

Comment: i have added screenshot link at the bottom, @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: @Axad so that means you haven't tried the last suggestion I made...

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre i have posted screnshot of image, i have tried your method too

Comment: @Axad you haven't tried what I said, the parenthesis are misplaced

Answer (score 1):

You must strictly separate

- the value of a date-time

and

- the textual representation

**What you see is *not* the actual value**. Especially with date-time values this might get quite tricky: How this is translated into *readable text* is depending on many factors: System's culture, language, settings...

When you read a date-time from SQL-Server column (`DATETIME`) into C# variable (`DateTime`) there exists no readable text. But when you set the lable's `Text`-property, you probably used `.ToString()`. At this moment the default settings are used.

However you set the value to the lable's text, you must pass in culture/format info to get this in the way you need it.